# Implementing a delay timer into triggered method

Tags: c#, unity

I have a shoot method that is used as a mouseDown() Trigger on my player. I am wanting to introduce a delayTimer but am unsure of how to do this within the method due to the trigger.

```
public void Shoot(){
    if (BulletsManager.bullets > 0 && facingRight == true) {
        playShotgunSound();
        Instantiate (Bullet, firePoint2.position, firePoint2.rotation);
        BulletsManager.SubtractPoints (bulletsToSubtract);
        facingLeft = false;
        facingRight = true;
    }

        if (BulletsManager.bullets > 0 && facingLeft == true) {
        playShotgunSound();
        Instantiate (Enemy, firePoint2.position, firePoint2.rotation);
        BulletsManager.SubtractPoints (bulletsToSubtract);
        facingLeft = true;
        facingRight = false;
    }
}
```

Could anybody advise as to how I'd implement it within this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was best to set up a Coroutine and calling each separate Coroutine within each if statement. The reason for this is a Coroutine allowed me to utilise

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds (shotDelay);
```

For more info reference: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html

Answer (score 0):

Without a bit more clarification, it sounds like using invoke to delay the execution of a method might be what you need. Check out this script reference for Unity: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html

Comment: I ended up calling a Coroutine and using:

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (shotDelay);

This allowed me to have a delay between each mouseDown();